# Outdoor outlet lost power

Tags: receptacle, outdoor

Christmas decoration lights were plugged into outlet while sprinklers were running. Came to find out lights were out, outlet had no power, and all other outdoor outlets around the house lost power. Probably related to sprinkles. None of outdoor outlets have those test/rest buttons but all are enclosed in special protective covers. No other outlets in the house lost power. No breakers were tripped on the panel. Tried resetting them all anyway, to no avail. Checked exterior, attic and garage for any additional breaker panels - nothing. What is my next step in identifying the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is there an outlet *inside* the house that has TEST and RESET buttons on it?

Comment: There’s one in the garage - tested it and didn’t help. There’s one at the patio that still works and without me resetting anything. There are a few at the kitchen that still work no problem. So probably al problematic ones are on a single breaker that I can’t identify?

Comment: Keep looking -- it could be anywhere within the house, really.

Comment: Check the bathrooms.

Comment: Good advice to keep looking - I’ve almost given up! Found it hidden under some garage shelf, put by previous owners (only had this house for a few months). Thanks all! How do I close the question?

Comment: @OlegYepifantsev You don't need to close it.  However, you can self-answer your question, and that generally tells others that there's no need to answer.  Also, you can get reputation points, which helps you participate later (assuming you tie your account to an email instead of a perishable cookie).

Comment: It is nice when questions are closed as the quit popping up unless someone else finds it and upvotes thin it shows up again. You should upvote the comments that helped if you haven’t already and then answer and accept that answer to close it.